# when user inputs string program returns you to the start of the loop, when integer program continues

Tags: java

Bellow you can see the part of the code i am having trouble with. So far when user inputs "a" the program returns an error. I would like the program to return "Wrong entry try again!" and goes back to the start od do statment.

```
do{
    System.out.println("Vnesi dožino besede, ki jo iščeš");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    dolzina = in.nextInt();
        }while (dolzina<0);
```

Comment: for what value of  dolzina would you like to repeat the loop. What error are you getting. Please be a bit more clear

Comment: use `hasNextInt()`  before calling `nextInt();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you, you can check if the [`Scanner.hasNextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29) before you try and read it. And, you should declare the `Scanner` once. Something like,

```
int dolzina = -1;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
do {
    System.out.println("Vnesi dožino besede, ki jo iščeš");
    if (in.hasNextInt()) {
        dolzina = in.nextInt();
    } else if (in.hasNextLine()) {
        System.out.printf("Wrong entry (%s) try again!%n",
                in.nextLine());
    } else {
        System.out.println("No Entry!");
        System.exit(1);
    }
} while (dolzina < 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
do{
    System.out.println("Vnesi dožino besede, ki jo iščeš");
    try {
        dolzina = in.nextInt();
    } catch ( InputMismatchException e ) {
        dolzina = -1;
        System.err.println( "Wrong entry, try again" );
    }
} while (dolzina<0);
```

This will catch the exception that the scanner is throwing when it expects an int and gets something else. When that happens, it will put a negative number in `dolzina` which, by your loop condition, will cause it to redo the loop.

The scanner should be opened **outside the loop**.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if int passed with in.hasNextInt().

```
    if (in.hasNextInt()) {
        dolzina = in.nextInt();
    }
```